# Rmarkdown 'saving' an exact place of the html page

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I've created two Rmarkdown pages that are linked together. I'd like to know if there is a way to code that the links direct to a specific spot on each page.

````
---
title: "Page 1"
author: "--"
date: "22 9 2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

### Header

example text.

#### example plot 1.

```{r cars}
plot(cars)
```

more example text

#### example plot 2.

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

link to [Page 2](./Page-2.html)
````

And Page 2:

````
---
title: "Page 2"
author: "--"
date: "22 9 2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

### Header

example text.

#### example plot 1.

```{r cars}
plot(cars)
```

more example text

#### example plot 2.

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

[Page 1](./Page-1.html)
````

For example, I'd like the page 2 link to redirect straight to the second graph. Moreso, when clicking back to page 1 - is there a way for it to save the spot I was currently looking at?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not provided for HTML output of rmarkdown/knitr. However, you can easily implement this using javaScript (jquery):

The idea is to include a small script that saves the last scroll position in a variable (I've called it `ScrPos` below) in local memory and restores the scroll position when the page is (re)loaded.

**header.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  // check if ScrPos is available. If so, scroll to ScrPos
  $(function() {
    if (localStorage.ScrPos) {
      $(window).scrollTop(localStorage.ScrPos);
    }
  });

  // save last scroll position  to ScrPos before page unload
  $(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
    var ScrPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    localStorage.setItem("ScrPos", ScrPos);
  });
</script>
```

You may include *header.html* in the YAML header (of both) .rmd files like this:

```yaml
output: 
  html_document:
    include:
      in_header: header.html
```

Note that *header.html* needs to be in the same directory as the .Rmd.

Answer (score 1):

for the linking to the second graph part it can be easily achieved by using the `div` id that's used for the second graph, either by explicitly assigning it or by using transforming the spaced section title to a dash separated one `` `example plot 2.` => id = `example-plot-2.` `` i.e:

#### New code for page 2

````
#### example plot 2.{#second_graph}

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

[Page 1](./Page-1.html)
````

and then in page one simply add the id to the link i.e:

```
link to [pressure graph](./Page-2.html#second_graph)
```